# Why wont my navbar collapse when on mobile on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to collapse the navbar when on mobile but the navbar only collapses when i resize the tab manualy. So it probably has something to do with it not checking the size of the screen when starting up the site. I've already tried some stuff with addeventlisteners but i just keep getting errors because op unexpected tokens. my original code was:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "190px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "190px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}





var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes


function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
      
      closeNav()
    
  }
    
  
}
```

after asking some people for help i eventualy started to mess around with this:

```
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)")
x.addEventListener("change", () => {
    myFunction(x);
});
```

and

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
 var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)")
 if (x.matches) { // If media query matches 
  closeNav() 
 }
 });
```

I have been awake for hours and i know it's probably something stupid.

Comment: It's obvious that, it won't work because you have added event listener as resize to the window. In mobile its not really possible to resize/change the window size, because of this your javascript code is not executing. You need media query for this. I would recommend you to drop this js idea and use media query instead. Here's the link to the media query docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 2):

Instead of JavaScript you can use CSS @media-queries like:

**@media only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 767px)
{
'your style here'
}**

**@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)
{
'for tablet portrait view'
}**

**@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)
{
'tablet view landscape'
}**

Also please don't forget to add viewport meta tag in your page  section.

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=3"

(keep above meta tag inside < />  )

view port meta tag will read your browser resizing and you can achieve to response web layout, show and hide elements in specific device sizes etc.

Comment: Yeah, but i'm trying to collapse a navbar so i need to use javascript.

Comment: i guess you are not using any UI Framework like bootstrap. as per my understanding you have a navigation menu full open in desktop and when it is opening in mobile or resize the browser it should collapse and become mobile menu? JS can not refresh automatically on browser resizing unless you refresh the page that is the problem to use JS. Also just try to use modernizr.js by which you can write JS media queries like css in JS style.  https://modernizr.com/. Remember JS queries will not execute on resizing only CSS will.